# CarouFredSel will load in Firefox but not in Safari or Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, carousel

I am wondering why this is happening.

My page: [LINK HERE](http://lucasnascimento.com/AW12carousel_content.html)

loads ok in Firefox but in Safari and Chrome it needs a refresh of some sort to get it right...
I'm not sure why this is happening. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

> **Please update your code in JqueryCarouFredsel-5.5.0.js page.**

1. Please find the code here http://jsfiddle.net/xnnN8/1/
2. Replace this code in your JqueryCarouFredsel-5.5.0.js

Comment: If you get any doubt Please let me know at mahi6535@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the sizes of your images

Using the HTML attributes:

```
<img src="image1.jpg" width="140" height="140" />
```

Via CSS:

```
#foo img {
width   : 140px;
height  : 140px;
```

}

Via the plugin configuration:

```
$("#foo").carouFredSel({

items   : {
    width   : 140,
    height  : 140
}
```

});